# Compile coffeescript with grunt -> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

I try to compile my coffeescript file with grunt using the [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-coffee) plugin. But running `grunt coffee`, I always get this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This is my grunt.js file:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    meta: {
      version: '0.1.0',
      banner: '/*! PROJECT_NAME - v<%= meta.version %> - ' +
        '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
        '* http://PROJECT_WEBSITE/\n' +
        '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> ' +
        'YOUR_NAME; Licensed MIT */'
    },
    lint: {
      files: ['grunt.js', 'lib/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']
    },
    qunit: {
      files: ['test/**/*.html']
    },
    concat: {
      dist: {
        src: ['<banner:meta.banner>', '<file_strip_banner:lib/FILE_NAME.js>'],
        dest: 'dist/FILE_NAME.js'
      }
    },
    min: {
      dist: {
        src: ['<banner:meta.banner>', '<config:concat.dist.dest>'],
        dest: 'dist/FILE_NAME.min.js'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: '<config:lint.files>',
      tasks: 'lint qunit'
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        immed: true,
        latedef: true,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        undef: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true,
        browser: true
      },
      globals: {}
    },
    uglify: {},
    coffee: {
      compile: {
        files: {
          'javascript/result.js': 'lib/grayScott.coffee'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'lint qunit concat min');
  grunt.registerTask('coffee', 'coffee');

};
```

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with your grunt file. Could you show the failing .coffee file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following line to your grunt.js file to load the `grunt-contrib-coffee` task (after the task has been install, ie `npm install grunt-contrib-coffee`:

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');`

Then remove this line: `grunt.registerTask('coffee', 'coffee');`. That line is trying to register the coffee task to itself and is the likely cause of the `RangeError`.